# Make an html element appear when page is scrolled down

Tags: html, css

I want my "Back to top" button to appear when the user scrolls about half down the webpage not immediately once the web page shows up. How would you be able to do that using HTML and CSS?

Element I want to appear about half way down and click to go back to the top:

```
<a href="#topPage"><img id="upArrow" src="Images/arrow-up.png" alt="Up arrow"></a>
```

Comment: I've just updated my answer, works fine. Just place your link into the middle of the page.

Comment: If you could do me a favor and mark my answer as correct that'd make us even. Happy coding ;)

Comment: Btw just noticed something else. There's no need to have `<a></a>` for this. A blank link will auto return you to the top of the page, but it wont involve jQuery, it essentially just reloads your page.

The code below just involves the user clicking on your image for it to work. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let me know if this works:**

*Edit: Added animation to return user to top on .click*

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function () { 
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('body').height() / 2) {
$('#upArrow').fadeTo(500, 1);
} 
});

$('#upArrow').click(function(){
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
});
</script>
```

**Set your upArrow as:**

```
<img id="upArrow" style="opacity: 0;" src="Images/arrow-up.png" alt="Up arrow"/>
```

**Alternative .js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
var scroll_pos_test = 500 // Edit this number to define how far down the page the div fades in.

if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
$('#upArrow').fadeTo(500, 1);
}
});

});
$('#upArrow').on("click",function(){
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

});
```

Comment: So I added the script to the header and changed my upArrow element as what you did but it didn't work. The only thing it did was make the upArrow invisible. I'm pretty sure I did something wrong can you please clarify further.

Comment: Include <script src='file.js'></script> under your arrow, may work then

Comment: Would this be different if it was on a fixed nav bar?

Comment: No, I use it on one.

I'll add an alternative in my answer for you to have a play with.

Comment: The question was how to do this in HTML and CSS.

Comment: The jQuery tag was there earlier, I checked.

Comment: Yes but the question originally stated "in HTML and CSS" so I deleted those.